# Python dynamic for loop range size

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, range

I'm trying to add `Link` argument to ini file by using python. Example of ini file:

```
[sometag]
sometext
sometext
sometext

[sometag2]
sometext2
sometext2
sometext2

[sometag3]
sometext3
sometext3
sometext3
```

I need to do like this:

```
[sometag]
sometext
sometext
sometext

Link = [sometag]

[sometag2]
sometext2
sometext2
sometext2

Link = [sometag2]
...
```

My for loop:

```
for i in range(len(m)):
    if m[i] in t:
        for j in xrange(i, len(m)):
            if len(m[j].strip()) == 0 and m[j+1].startswith('['):
                m.insert(j, Link.....
                break


# m = ini_file.readlines()
# t = ['[sometag]', '[sometag2]']
```

My code works, but it does not add Link for last tags. I've found why. If I add `in range(len(m)+100):` Then code adds all Links.

Looks like `len(m)` is old value (static?), because I'm increasing len with insert during loop. Any ideas?

I have tried something like
    `insertings = 0`, then `range(len(m)+insertings)` and afer insert `insertings = insertings+1` But no luck :(

Comment: If it is a small `.ini` file why not creating a new and then renaming the file? `len(m)` yes it won't change over time and your list will become inconsistent.

Comment: @mad_ thanks for reply. It is not small ini file :(

Comment: I have a new idea. I can count lines before loop, right? current lines count + len of t * 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a **new** list:

```
new = []
tag = None
for line in m:
    if line.startswith('['):
        if tag:
            new.append('Link = ' + tag)
        tag = line
    new.append(line)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `range` locks you to a specific number of iterations; `range(len(m))` constructs a `range` using the value of `len(m)` *now*, and it's never changed (it can't be `range`s are immutable). You *want* this behavior, in the same way you want:

```
s = '123'
i = int(s)
s = 'abc'
```

to leave `i` with the value `123`, rather than dying when `int`'s argument retroactively becomes `'abc'` (allowing `range(len(m))`'s behavior to retroactively change as `m` changes would be morally equivalent, and equally insane).

Modifying a `list` while iterating over it is frowned upon, especially if you're `insert`ing before the end of the `list`, or deleting elements. It's just too error-prone; in this case, when `j` takes the initial value of `i`, and an `insert` occurs, you've inserted a value that the loops will never see (because it will look at `i + 1` next), while inserting it at `j > i` will be seen by the outer loop, but not the inner (and in both cases, the value of `m[j]` will get processed twice, on consecutive loops).

Generally, the safer solution is to build a new `list` from scratch, adding the elements from the existing `list` as needed, and new elements to the end as you go. It's also much faster `insert`ing to the middle of a `list` is `O(n)` for *each* `insert` (overall cost `O(m * n)` where `m` is number of insertions required, `n` is input size), while `append` is amortized `O(1)` (overall cost `O(m + n)`).